# PHP script restarting while importing a big MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, import

This is a problem I'm having for quite some time now.
I work for a banking institute: our service provider lets us access our data via ODBC through a proprietary DB engine.
Since I need almost a hundred tables for our internal procedures and whatnot, I set up some "replication" scripts, put em in a cron and basically reloading from scratch the tables I need every morning.

When the number of records is small (approx. 50.000 records and 100 columns or so) everything goes smooth, but whenever I get a medium-big table (approx. 700.000 records), more often than not the script restarts itself (I look at my MySQL tables while the import scripts are running and I see them going 400k, 500k... and back from 1).

This is an example of one of my import scripts:

```
   <?php

   ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
   $connect = odbc_connect('XXXXX', '', '') or die ('0');

   $empty_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE SADAS.".$NOME_SCRIPT;
   $SQL->query($empty_query);

   $select_query = "   SELECT...
                       FROM ...";

   $result = odbc_exec($connect, $select_query);
   while($dati = odbc_fetch_object($result)) {

    $insert_query = "   INSERT INTO ...
                        VALUES ...";

    $SQL->Query($insert_query);

   }

   // Close ODBC
   odbc_close($connect);

   ?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: when you say 400k then back to 1, what parameter are you looking at? do you mean a non-unique but sequencial field increament to 400k but the next entry value goes back to 1? or did the whole table got truncate and reinsert from the start?

Comment: Yeah, sorry... kinda misleading.
I'm using a GUI for all the MySQL things (Navicat), and while refreshing the general view to see the insertion progress, I see the "row numbers" column going up... and then restarting from 1.
Even 2-3 times :/